# How to access variable from one component into another component in angular?

Tags: angular

I have two components users_profile_component and userslist component  now i want to access is_added variable in user_profile_component in userslist component 
I tried using @viewchild @Input but every time it gives me error cant access property of undefined

Comment: Please add relevant code

Comment: Please, before we can give you a correct answer, specify the relation of the components. parent>child, child>parent, component-component.

Answer (score 0):

**Angular Services** is exactly what you need.
Tons of tutorials on the web, here's one: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Answer (score 0):

The first question in this problem is know where is that variable, in the parent? in the child?.

If you want to hace access from the child component to a parent's property, you must use bindings

```
class Parent {
   property = 1;
}

//
// Parent HMTL
<child [prop]="property">

class Child {
@Input() prop;
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log (this.prop); // 1
  }
}
```

Comment: He said he want to access variables from another "component", this can be done by Angular Services.

Comment: He not has specified the relation of the components. There are three use cases, one of those is parent>child, other child>parent and another one is component-component.

Comment: Indeed he did not specified the relation, but I highly assume he means component - component.